# ASP.NET deploy to IIS7: To default site root, app in default site, or separate site?

Tags: asp.net, deployment, iis-7, virtual-machine

I'm sort of new to IIS7, and I sort of get the differences between sites, applications, and virtual dirs.  However, I'm not quite sure what the best deployment approach would be for my specific situation.

I have a clean windows '08 server VM with a IIS/asp.net set up.  I set up an FTP site with C:\inetpub\wwwroot as the FTP root thinking I could do a quick "copy site" from VS to this root.

However, before I do the copy, I want to make sure this is the quickest, safest approach.

Please note that, this VM will be soley dedicated to my asp.net app (for testing purposes), and I'm kind of under the gun having to get this app running by EOD today.

That said, my questions is, should I...

1. simply do a "copy site" directly to the default site's root and
   leverage the default app pool that's already been created, or
2. add a new application under the default site (if I do this, should I select the default app pool, or create new ones), or
3. add a whole new web site?

Also, while I'm at it... My app was built with asp.net 4. Should I select the Default App Pool, or the ASP.NET 4.0 Integrated ones?

Thank you,
Ed

Comment: IMO, if you are hosting just one site, I would use the default app. Simple, straight-forward and easy to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would setup IIS:

1. Create a new site (I always name the sites by the domain that they will be using)
2. Creating a new site will create a new application pool.  Verify that the application pool is using .NET 4.0 Integrated.

Answer (score 0):

Copy/Publish your site to a folder and then host this folder.
IF you host it under default web site, your url to the site will be http:// machinename/sitename or http:// localhost /sitename
In the other case you will host your site directly on a specified port or you can even host it under :80 port, and will be accessible directly through your machine name. Choose the application pool that is in integrated mode with supported version of 4.0 and you won't have any problems ( usually default app pool is configured with these settings)